Отправка сообщений discord чезер JS (Не через бота)
Не могу разобраться как написать код на JavaScript для отправки сообщений в Discord.
Не через бота а через другой аккаунт. При моих попытках он просто выдает Error sending message: { message: '401: Unauthorized', code: 0 }

При каких попытках?

Ваш вопрос могут закрыть из за отсутствия конкретики. Нужно отредактировать его, приведя свой код. Без этого - ответ вряд ли будет. Но я Вам могу сказать, что, скорее всего, там просто "не работает". То есть, если JS-код - на странице какого то сайта, то взаимодействовать этот js код должен с серверной частью, а уже там - работать какая то штука, которая отправляет сообщения. А вот по Вашей ошибке вообще понятно, что авторизации нет - может, вы это в Node.js запускаете?
